# Clone/branch for bug fix and merge through multiple versions in Mercurial

Tags: merge, mercurial

I'd like to achieve the following workflow with Mercurial:

working on version 7.4 in default branch

finding an error in 7.1 (7.2 uses a different DB layout, so I want to quick fix the error based on 7.1), branching or cloning to a bugfix.

releasing 7.1.1

Now my problem is that I'd like to merge the bugfix changes into 7.2, and up until the current development (7.4). I only found ways to merge with current, but that leaves 7.2 and 7.3 without the 7.1.1 fix.
How shall I set up my repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical Layout is such that you have the default branch where you develop new features.

From that default branch you regularily branch-off the individual major release branches (thus your 7.1, 7.2, 7.3... in your case).

If you now encounter a bug, you fix it in the oldest version where it is present, thus a bug affecting a 7.1.x release is fixed in the 7.1 branch. Then you merge the 7.1 branch in every other branch where it also needs fixing, thus probably 7.2, 7.3, 7.4 and default (=development) branch. As all branches have a newer base than the oldest one (and you fixed it there), no old stuff will be merged (your merge tool should recognize that).

If you prefer not to merge, you can use graft to simply copy the fixes to the other branches.

Answer (score 1):

One option, use `hg graft`. Works like merge, but will keep branches open.